# Merging two columns into one in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with two columns `hora_entrada` and `hora_saida` and when running this select statement:

```
select hora_entrada, hora_saida  
from Controlo_de_Entrada_saidas
```

it shows this result:

[image]

What I want to do is to combine these two columns into one that if `Hora_saida = "Não saiu"`, it shows the data in `hora_entrada` but if `hora_saída` has an actual hour in there, it shows the data in `hora_saida` instead.

So basically this should be my result:

[image]

I don't know if I'm making myself clear, I actually don't even know where to start or if its even possible but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    hora_entrada,
    hora_saida,
    CASE WHEN hora_saida = 'Não saiu'
         THEN hora_entrada ELSE hora_saida END AS new_column
FROM yourTable;
```

This logic assumes that any value in the `hora_saida` column which is *not* `Não saiu` is a valid timestamp.  If not, then we could add additional logic to check for this as well.

If you are open/able to changing your data model, you might want to consider just storing `NULL` values for the missing data.  SQL Server (and most other databases as well) has a built-in function `COALESCE`, which can be used to replace `NULL` with a backup value.  This would avoid needing to use a lengthy `CASE` expression as you see above.

Comment: I am not sure but don't you need N prefix before 'Não saiu'?

Comment: @uzi It looks like [we don't the N unicode prefix](http://rextester.com/IBCPZO12540), as varchar covers Portuguese, a Romance language.

Comment: ah thank you! i did not know about the case expression, now i feel dumb xD.